# Traversing recursively through an array and modifying values of object properties in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

***The post may seem lengthy but it's quite easy to follow, if not, I will add more details***

I have `criteria` array which that looks like :

```
   let criteria = [
        "and",
        {
          "Collection": "persons",
          "Property": "phone",
          "operator": "eq",
          "operatorValue": "$p:phone"  
        },
        {
          "Collection": "persondetails",
          "Property": "country",
          "operator": "eq",
          "operatorValue": "$p:country" 
        },
        ["or",
        {
          "Collection": "persons",
          "Property": "city",
          "operator": "eq",
          "operatorValue": "$p:city"  
        }]
      ]
```

**Characteristics of `criteria`:**

1. It could have nested arrays.
2. First item array (or nested array) is always going to be either "and" or "or"
3. Second item onwards in array, item could be either an object with this specific structure

`{ "Collection": "persons", "Property": "phone", "operator": "eq", "operatorValue": "$p:phone" }`

or it could be an array like:

`["or", { "Collection": "persons", "Property": "city", "operator": "eq", "operatorValue": "$p:city" }]`

4. Object is never going to be nested object

There is also a `parameters` object:

```
let parameters = {phone:"23138213", "country": "Russia", "city":"york"}
```

The aim is to recursively traverse through all the `operatorValue` properties in the `criteria` array and if you encounter value such as  `$p:phone`, it is to be replaced by whatever `parameters["phone"]` evaluate to.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
[
    "and",
    {
      "Collection": "persons",
      "Property": "phone",
      "operator": "eq",
      "operatorValue": "23138213"  
    },
    {
      "Collection": "persondetails",
      "Property": "country",
      "operator": "eq",
      "operatorValue": "Russia" 
    },
    ["or",
    {
      "Collection": "persons",
      "Property": "city",
      "operator": "eq",
      "operatorValue": "york"  
    }]
  ]
```

I was able to recursively traverse through the array. The only problem is that I can't figure out how to modify the original `criteria` variable.

[REPL](https://repl.it/@jimrock/SoulfulCourteousStructure#index.js)

Please see the line 43 in repl. `item[1]=parameters[item[1].split('$p:')[1]]`
I understand why it won't modify the criteria, its because item over here is a different variable in different scope altogether.

**Failed Attempt :**

```
  function traverse(obj,parameters){
  
    obj.forEach((item,index)=>{
      
      
     if( typeof item == 'string' ){
       //do nothing
     }
     else if( !(item instanceof Array)){
         
       Object.entries(item).forEach((item,index)=>{
         
         if( item[1] instanceof Array){ 
                      
           traverse(item,parameters);
         }else{
           if(item[1].startsWith('$p:')){
               item[1]=parameters[item[1].split('$p:')[1]] //values dont get replaced for obvious reason
               console.log(item[1])
           } 
         }
       })        
     }
     else if( item  instanceof Array){           
           traverse(item,parameters);
      }  
    })
  }

  traverse(criteria,parameters)
  console.log(criteria)
```

How do I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your function. You don't need to loop through the entries of the object. You also don't need to `split` the `operationValue`. That mapping key of `parameters` is present in the `Property` key.

- Loop through each item in the array and check if the item is an `Array`.
- If yes, recursively call `traverse` on the item.
- If it is an object, update its `operatorValue` property with `parameters[val.Property]`

```js
function traverse(arr, parameters) {
  for (const item of arr) {
    if (Array.isArray(item))
        traverse(item, parameters)
    else if (typeof item === 'object')
        item.operatorValue = parameters[item.Property]
  }
  return arr
}

let criteria=["and",{Collection:"persons",Property:"phone",operator:"eq",operatorValue:"$p:phone"},{Collection:"persondetails",Property:"country",operator:"eq",operatorValue:"$p:country"},["or",{Collection:"persons",Property:"city",operator:"eq",operatorValue:"$p:city"}]],
    parameters = {phone:"23138213", "country": "Russia", "city":"york"};

console.log(traverse(criteria, parameters))
```

Comment: I wonder why this works but my solution doesn't. Is it because `obj.forEach((item,index)=>{}` creates a new  `item` but `for (const item of arr) {}` doesn't?

Comment: @SamuraiJack You need to rename `Object.entries(item).forEach((item)` <- item paraeter to something else. Because there is an `item` variable outside. `item[1]=parameters[item[1].split('$p:')[1]]` is just going to update the entries array. It will not update the outside `item` obejct you want to update

Comment: Your logic is difficult to follow, but `item[1]=parameters[item[1].split('$p:')[1]]` just reassigns the second item from `Object.entries` which is a simple string inside an array. That doesn't change the original object--you need a reference to the object to change a property on it.

Comment: @SamuraiJack also, you don't need to loop thorugh the entries of the object. You know the properties before hand. The `split` is also not necessary since the `Property` key of each object already holds the key from `parameters` you want to take

Comment: Thank you @adiga

Comment: But there is one problem.  The `"operatorValue"` is not always going to have a placehoder value. For eg: it could be `"operatorValue": "London"`    instead of `"operatorValue": "$p":city`

Comment: In which case it shouldnt blindly replace the value with parameter

Comment: @SamuraiJack you can just add that to the condition: `else if(typeof item === 'object' && item.operatorValue.startsWith('$p:'))`

Comment: @adiga yes, yes. I was just saying.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the key of the object for assigning the value.

```js
function traverse(obj, parameters) {
    obj.forEach(item => {
        if (item instanceof Array) return traverse(item, parameters);
        if (item?.operatorValue?.startsWith('$p:')) {
            item.operatorValue = parameters[item.operatorValue.split('$p:')[1]];
        }
    });
}

const
    criteria = ["and", { Collection: "persons", Property: "phone", operator: "eq", operatorValue: "$p:phone" }, { Collection: "persondetails", Property: "country", operator: "eq", operatorValue: "$p:country" }, ["or", { Collection: "persons", Property: "city", operator: "eq", operatorValue: "$p:city" }]],
    parameters = { phone: "23138213", "country": "Russia", "city": "york" };

traverse(criteria, parameters);
console.log(criteria);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why is it that this solution works but mine doesn't?

Comment: you assign to an array with the value of the object. it has no reference to the object by taking the entries of the object. to overcome this, you need the object and a key and assign the new value to it.

Comment: Thank you Nina. It was such a silly mistake on my part. I marked adiga's answer because he was first.  :)  +1

Comment: @SamuraiJack You should pick the best answer, not the first answer.

Comment: @ggorlen and what do you do when they are both equally good?

Comment: @SamuraiJack Seems hard to believe, pick whichever you want, but I'm just saying, people get a lot of imaginary ideas about fairness when accepting answers and feel compelled to pick suboptimal solutions that don't benefit the community as a result. Nobody is going to fault you for picking something other than the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

A clean recursive version:

```js
const traverse = ([conj, ...nodes], params) => [
  conj, 
  ... nodes .map (node => Array .isArray (node) 
        ? traverse (node, params)
        : {... node, operatorValue: params [nodes .Property]}
      )
]

const criteria = ["and", {Collection: "persons", Property: "phone", operator: "eq",operatorValue: "$p:phone"}, {Collection: "persondetails", Property: "country", operator: "eq", operatorValue: "$p:country"}, ["or", {Collection: "persons", Property: "city", operator: "eq", operatorValue: "$p:city"}]]
const parameters = {phone:"23138213", "country": "Russia", "city":"york"}


console .log (traverse (criteria, parameters))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This only works if the simplification from adiga holds up that the object's `Property` node has the same value as the suffix in the `operatorValue` one.  If not, I would probably use a regex replace to handle that, and separate it into a helper function:

```js
const replaceOpValue = (params) => (obj) => ({
  ... obj, 
  operatorValue: obj .operatorValue .replace (/\$p:(.+)/, ((_, key) => params [key]))
})
  

const traverse = ([conj, ...nodes], params) => [
  conj, 
  ... nodes .map (node => Array .isArray (node) 
        ? traverse (node, params)
        : replaceOpValue (params) (node)
      )
]
```

Comment: Just saw the comment thread that explained that value wouldn't always be replaced.  The second version here would still work.  It does not however handle the case the the property sought is not in the parameters object.  I assume that then it would need to  default back to the original value with something like: `(_, key) => params [key] || obj .operatorValue`, or a more sophisticated version of the same thing if the acceptable parameter values included false-y ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). Might be a bit more flexible and maintainable depending on your requirements

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const criteria = [ 'and', { Collection: 'persons', Property: 'phone', operator: 'eq', operatorValue: '$p:phone' }, { Collection: 'persondetails', Property: 'country', operator: 'eq', operatorValue: '$p:country' }, [ 'or', { Collection: 'persons', Property: 'city', operator: 'eq', operatorValue: '$p:city' } ] ];

const substitute = (obj, params) => objectScan(['**.operatorValue'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ value, parent, property }) => {
    if (value.startsWith('$p:') && value.slice(3) in params) {
      parent[property] = params[value.slice(3)];
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(obj);

console.log(substitute(criteria, { phone: '23138213', country: 'Russia', city: 'york' })); // returns number of substitutions
// => 3

console.log(criteria);
// => [ 'and', { Collection: 'persons', Property: 'phone', operator: 'eq', operatorValue: '23138213' }, { Collection: 'persondetails', Property: 'country', operator: 'eq', operatorValue: 'Russia' }, [ 'or', { Collection: 'persons', Property: 'city', operator: 'eq', operatorValue: 'york' } ] ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)